# React check is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I'm building my first app in React I have some difficulties with checking is something nulled.

This is constructor

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      title: '',
      price: '',
      off_price: '',
      category_id: '',
      arttitle: '',
      artbody: '',
      shown: false,
      editDisabled: false,
      items: []
    }
    getAll = () => {
      const {
        categoryid
      } = this.props;
      getProducts(categoryid).then(data => {
        this.setState({
            title: '',
            price: '',
            off_price: '',
            category_id: this.props.categoryid,
            items: [...data]
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.items)
          }
        )
      })
    }
```

And this is how I'm listing what is needed

```
{this.state.items.map((item, index) => ( 
... 
))}
```

Now I have one simple div that I need to show only if this.state.items is nulled.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

Since `items` is already declared as an array in state you can simply test for length instead:

```
render() {

  if (!this.state.items.length) return <div>Items is null</div>

  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {...}
    </div>
  );

}
```